# Making form fields nonempty and calculating averages from form data involving some empty fields using php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, count

I've been trying to:(i) make my form fields nonempty using php scripts and
(ii) calculate average of numerical form data inserted into an array and an element of the array could be empty. For instance, suppose the form is used to harvest students' scores, some student might not offer an optional subject. How to adapt the count() array function in this instance is my headache. I admit that some folks have posed  questions that partially addressed it but some issues remain unsolved,  hence this post.
In summary:(i) the code below executes even when some form fields are empty, against my wish.(ii) If I grant some form fields to be empty; the result of the average calculation is incorrect; also against my wish
Code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['candidate'];
$Eng_CA = $_POST['Eng_CA'];
$Eng_Ex = $_POST['Eng_Ex'];
$Math_CA = $_POST['Math_CA'];
$Math_Ex = $_POST['Math_Ex'];
$Comp_CA = $_POST['Comp_CA'];
$Comp_Ex = $_POST['Comp_Ex'];
$engSum = $Eng_CA + $Eng_Ex;
$mathSum = $Math_CA + $Math_Ex;
$compSum = $Comp_CA + $Comp_Ex;
$tot = array();
$tot[] = $engSum;
 $tot[]=  $mathSum;
$tot[] = $compSum;
 $total = array_sum($tot);
 $Average = $total/count($tot); // Average is incorrcet if some fields are empty
$notEmpty = array();

$notEmpty = array('$name', '$Eng_CA', '$Eng_Ex', '$Math_CA', '$Math_Ex', '$Comp_CA', '$Comp_Ex');

foreach ($notEmpty as $notEmp){ // this is not working; code executes anyway
```

HTML

```
<form action ='test_Code.php' method ='post'>
<table width ='600'>
<tr><td> Cand Name</td><td colspan ='2'><input type ='text' name = 'candidate' size = '60'></td></tr>
<th>Subject</th><th>CA</th><th>Exam</th>

<tr><td>Eng</td><td><input type ='text' name = 'Eng_CA'/></td><td><input type ='text' name = 'Eng_Ex'/></td></tr>

<tr><td>Math</td><td><input type ='text' name = 'Math_CA'/></td><td><input type ='text' name = 'Math_Ex'/></td></tr>

<tr><td>Computer</td><td><input type ='text' name = 'Comp_CA'/></td><td><input type ='text' name = 'Comp_Ex'/></td></tr>
```

```
if(empty($notEmp)){
    echo"You have left some fields empty, fill them pls";
die();
```

}

```
}
echo"<table border ='1'>";
echo"<th>Candidate</th><th>Eng Ca</th><th>Eng Ex</th><th>Math Ca</th> <th>Math Ex</th> <th>Comp Ca</th><th>Comp ex</th><th>Total</th><th>Average</th>";
echo"<tr><td>";
echo $name ."</td><td>".$Eng_CA."</td><td>".$Eng_Ex."</td><td>".$Math_CA."</td><td>".$Math_Ex."</td><td>".$Comp_CA."</td><td>". $Comp_Ex."</td><td>".$total."</td><td>".$Average."</td></tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you validate empty fields on Javascript? And you can also check if they are empty on PHP before assigning them into variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trying to do a not empty check in an odd way to me.  What I would do personally is simply loop through your $_POST vars first.  Check them if they are empty.  If so die or error out.  example:

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST)): //this is how trigger the processes for any form

    foreach($_POST as $k => $v):
       if(empty($v)){
            echo $k.' can not be blank.<br>';
            $error .= '<div>'.$k.' can not be blank.</div>'; //here is another option...  

       }
    endforeach;
    //if you get here now do your averages or whatever you were wanting.

    endif;

//anywhere else in your entire php page write this
if($error){echo $error; } //this is a basic check, if error is empty it will be false, if error is not empty above it will print out the fields that

   ?>
```

Comment: Ok; thanks.  But:(ii) is there a way to ouput the empty elemnts of $_POST to the client so they can correct them?  Tried <?php echo "You left ". $v. "Filed Empty" ?> but it's not working. (ii) Second part of original question, line 16; that's what bred this question. - Stephen Carr

Comment: Of course.  I changed the code above for you.  I was already checking if the field is empty and then I was killing the processes.  Now I made it so that it echo's out the field name and says that it cannot be blank.  You can also put those messages into a variable like $error and then echo them out below in your page so it looks more professional.  I have added that option for you as well.